# Pandas - groupby with condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to groupby my pandas dataframe based on a given range condition.
For example:

```
Number, Amount
1, 5
2, 10
3, 11
4, 3
5, 5
6, 8
7, 9
8, 6
```

Range conditions:

1 till 4 (included), named A: 5+10+11+3 = 29

5 and higher, named B: 5+8+9+6 = 28

Desired outcome:

```
Number, Amount
A, 29
B, 28
```

EDIT: Thanks for the great solutions.
I would like to be able to add more range conditions if needed, so 5-7 and 8 alone should also be a possibility. Is it possible to keep that flexible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut` also, helpful if you more that two labels and ranges:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Number'], 
                  bins=[0,4,np.inf], 
                  labels=['A', 'B']))['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Number  Amount
0      A      29
1      B      28
```

Comment: @Scripter.  the `pd.cut` method is pretty flexible by changing the bins and labels

Comment: Thanks, managed to add new bins and labels as well. Don't forget ```import numpy as np``` :)

Answer (score 4):

You can check values of `Number`, map it to `A,B` then groupby:

```
(df.Amount.groupby(df.Number.ge(5).map({True:'B',False:'A'}))
   .sum()
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  Number  Amount
0      A      29
1      B      28
```

Answer (score 2):

Using groupby with `np.where`

```
df.groupby(np.where(df.Number <= 4, 'A', 'B')).Amount.sum().reset_index()

Out[16]:
  index  Amount
0     A      29
1     B      28
```

If you need matching column name, just chain `rename_axis`

```
df_final = (df.groupby(np.where(df.Number <=4, 'A', 'B')).Amount.sum()
                                                         .rename_axis('Number')
                                                         .reset_index())

Out[25]:
  Number  Amount
0      A      29
1      B      28
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
import numpy as np
nos = df[(df.Number.between(1, 4)) | (df.Number >= 5)]
nos.groupby(np.where(nos.Number <= 4, 'A', 'B'))\
    .Amount.sum().reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={'index': 'Number'})
```

Output

```
  Number  Amount
0      A      29
1      B      28
```